# Notify purchases by Sale Order in Odoo

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

We are working in an Industrial Factory, the purchase's responsible must to inform to the CEO about any purchase for procuring manufacturing materials for a Sale Order product.

For example, we have a **Sale Order** `SO00005` with the product `[856A3779G02] PULLER – PLATFORM, FAN BLADE`, it has its own `BoM` and it also has the `MTO` and `Manufacture` route.

The system creates a new **PO**, the responsible edit and handles the route, and at confirm, we must send to the CEO a message like this:

> SO00005 adlı [856A3779G02] PULLER – PLATFORM, FAN BLADE projesi için
>   toplam maliyet 100.0₺'dir.
>
> SO00005 adlı [856A3779G02] PULLER – PLATFORM, FAN BLADE şindiye
>   kadarki toplam maliyet 1175.0₺.

Where the first one says the current material price, and the second one says the total per **Sale Order**.

How can we handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we will begin with the notification process. We can use here an [automated action](https://www.surekhatech.com/blog/automated-actions-in-odoo) in order to make this action the simplest possible.

## Automated Action

We go to `Settings > Technical > Automation > Automated Actions` (don't forget install the [base_automation](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/11.0/addons/base_automation) module), and we create a new action with the next parameters:

**Model**: `purchase.order`, we want to notify when the <kbd>CONFIRM ORDER</kbd> button is clicked, changing the current **Purchase Order** *state* to *purchase*.
**Trigger Condition**: On Update, we want to send this notification when the **Purchase Order** is confirmed, it means, when the **Purchase Order** change its *state* to `purchase`.
**Before Update Domain**: So, the prior domain will be all current draft, to approve or e-mail sent purchase orders, `["|","|",["state","=","draft"],["state","=","sent"],["state","=","to approve"]]`.
**Apply on**: We'll send this mail when the **Purchase Order**'s state change to `purchase`, `[["state","=","purchase"]]`.
**Action To Do**: finally, we will apply a python code in order to get the required information and send it to the boss.

## Python Code

We decided to use `python` code because it is easier to iterate over objects in code; we mean, we can also send emails as **Action To Do**, but in this case, we would require taking `purchase.order.line` as hour model and it could be harder.

Now, the simplest way consists in sending a message to a channel inside Odoo, keeping within the system as many procedures as we can. So, before to create this action we must [create a private or public channel](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/11.0/discuss/team_communication.html) in the discuss module.

Continuing with the code, we will obtain this channel for sending messages to it:

```
channel = env['mail.channel'].search([('name', '=', 'purchases-notify')])
channel.ensure_one()
```

Also, we need the *CEO* manager partner:

```
boss = env['res.partner'].search([('function', '=', 'CEO')])
```

Now, we will iterate over each *line* in the **Purchase Order** processing the information; we have to options here, by default, t[racking purchases and other expenses](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/11.0/accounting/others/analytic/purchases_expenses.html) in **Odoo** uses the accounting module and process, it means, we must to add analytical accounts to each line in the **Purchase Order**, and, if the **PO** has many different products, it could be very annoying. We will use other approaching.

Manufacturing order and sale orders generate**Procurement Group**s based in the **Procurement Rules**, and the **Procurement Group** [has a unique **Sale Order** origin](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/sale_stock/models/stock.py#L58), it is a double advantage for us; first one is that we can get the *product*'s name through this relationship; this **PG** has the **SO** name as its name too.

By default **Odoo** does not split each purchase line by **PG** groups, it just merges the lines if the *product* or *product variant* and the *uom* are the same, and also we cannot know which is the **PG** origin for it line; to solve this we must to install the [purchase_line_procurement_group](https://github.com/OCA/purchase-workflow/tree/11.0/purchase_line_procurement_group) module from [OCA](https://github.com/OCA/purchase-workflow).

We have the next code then:

```
for line in record.order_line:
  procurement_group = line.procurement_group_id
  product = env['sale.order'].search([('id', '=', procurement_group.sale_id.id)]).order_line[0].name
  sub_total = line.price_subtotal
```

Getting the line's product cost from the `price_subtotal` field.

But we want to get the total cost for **SO**: we get first all *purchase order lines* related to the current line's **PG**, then, we iterate over them summing just line which **PO** is also confirmed:

```
purchase_order_lines_list = env['purchase.order.line'].search([('procurement_group_id','=',procurement_group.id)])
  total = 0
  for line in purchase_order_lines_list:
    if line.order_id.state == 'purchase':
      total += line.price_subtotal
```

The second advantage, as we can see in the above code is: as each **PG** has just one **SO** origin, we don't need necessarily to search with the `procurement_group_id.sale_id.id` field, because of **PG** ID will be associate just to one **SO** and no other.

We have all the information that we need, then, we will send a new message for each line in the **PO**:

```
post_vars = {
    'subject': "Purchase {}".format(record.name),
    'body': '''<p>Mr. <strong>{0}</strong>,</p>
        <p><strong>{1}</strong> adlı <strong>{2}</strong> projesi için toplam maliyet <strong>{3}{4}</strong>'dir.</p>
        <p><strong>{1}</strong> adlı <strong>{2}</strong> şindiye kadarki toplam maliyet <strong>{5}{4}</strong>.</p>'''.format(boss.name, procurement_group.name, product, sub_total, line.currency_id.symbol, total)
  }
  channel.message_post(type="notification", subtype="mt_comment", **post_vars)
```

We must add the currency symbol, existing as a field in the line, which is `line.currency_id.symbol`.

Finally, our full code will be:

```
channel = env['mail.channel'].search([('name', '=', 'purchases-notify')])
channel.ensure_one()


boss = env['res.partner'].search([('function', '=', 'CEO')])

for line in record.order_line:
  procurement_group = line.procurement_group_id
  product = env['sale.order'].search([('id', '=', procurement_group.sale_id.id)]).order_line[0].name
  sub_total = line.price_subtotal
  purchase_order_lines_list = env['purchase.order.line'].search([('procurement_group_id','=',procurement_group.id)])
  total = 0
  for line in purchase_order_lines_list:
    if line.order_id.state == 'purchase':
      total += line.price_subtotal
  post_vars = {
    'subject': "Purchase {}".format(record.name),
    'body': '''<p>Mr. <strong>{0}</strong>,</p>
        <p><strong>{1}</strong> adlı <strong>{2}</strong> projesi için toplam maliyet <strong>{3}{4}</strong>'dir.</p>
        <p><strong>{1}</strong> adlı <strong>{2}</strong> şindiye kadarki toplam maliyet <strong>{5}{4}</strong>.</p>'''.format(boss.name, procurement_group.name, product, sub_total, line.currency_id.symbol, total)
  }
  channel.message_post(type="notification", subtype="mt_comment", **post_vars)
```

And we will get the next each time we confirm a **PO**:
[image]